# Setting all matplotlib axis labels at once

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Since I usually try to label my axes in matplotlib plots, I find that I regularly label the x/y/z axes individually, using something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
# <plot plot plot>
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

Is there a way to reduce the individual axis-label setting to one command, ideally something like `ax.set_labels(['x', 'y', 'z'])`?

Comment: You could monkey-patch that in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get close using `ax.update`. For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

ax.update({'xlabel':'x', 'ylabel':'y', 'zlabel':'z'})
```

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.update) for `ax.update`:

> update(props)
>
> Update the properties of this Artist from the dictionary prop.

So, you can update more than just axes labels using `ax.update`, so this could help reduce you code in other places too. Just pass whichever property to update in the dictionary. A list of available properties can be found using [`ax.properties()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.properties)